# Disable meshrenderer for multiple gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on some type of LOD system where I have some ferns that have to be enabled and disabled. I'm using a cube for this process, so when when my character touches the cube the ferns meshrenderers will be disabled and when not touching it, it'll enable them. Now the part where I struggle, is when I have to enable/disable the meshrenderes of these gameobjects tagged with fern.
Here is my code so far:

```
public GameObject[] FernPlants;
public MeshRenderer MR;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    FernPlants = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Fern");  
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        //Disable meshrenderers on FernPlants
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    //Enable meshrenderers on FernPlants
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
public GameObject[] FernPlants;
public MeshRenderer MR;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    FernPlants = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Fern");  
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        //Disable meshrenderers on FernPlants
        foreach(GameObject go in FernPlants)
        {
            go.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    //Enable meshrenderers on FernPlants
    foreach(GameObject go in FernPlants)
    {
        go.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```